# Matlab: contourf or colormap to plot filled ellipses according to radius

Tags: matlab, plot, ellipse, colormap, contourf

I am trying to use either the contourf or colormap functions to plot filled ellipses with colors according to their arcsin(b/a) value (a=major axis, b=minor axis).

```
clearvars -except data colheaders
close all
clc
data(:,9)=data(:,9)*pi/180; % Convers Column 9 (angle of rotation) in rad
data(:,6)=1196-data(:,6); % Reset the Y coordinate axis to bottom left

theta = 0 : 0.01 : 2*pi; % Converts phi in rad 

imax=29;
% Define colors
cvalues=asin(data(1:imax,8)./data(1:imax,7))./asin(1);
cm = colormap; % returns the current color map

% Sort and get their index to access the color array 
[~,idx] = sort(cvalues);

% Create colormap
%ColorMap=jet;

for i=1:imax

x = data(i,7)/2 * cos(theta) * cos(data(i,9)) - data(i,8)/2 * sin(theta) * sin(data(i,9)) + data(i,5);
y = data(i,8)/2 * sin(theta) * cos(data(i,9)) + data(i,7)/2 * cos(theta) * sin(data(i,9)) + data(i,6);

colorID = max(1, sum(cvalues(i) > [0:1/length(cm(:,1)):1])); 
ColorMap(i,:) = cm(colorID, :); % returns your color
hold on
% Columns (5,6) are the centre (x,y) of the ellipse
% Columns (7,8) are the major and minor axes (a,b)
% Column 9 is the rotation angle with the x axis

%% TRYING A FASTER WAY OF PLOTTING
%A(:,i)=x'; 
%B(:,i)=y';
%%
fill(x,y,ColorMap(i,:),'EdgeColor', 'None')
text(data(i,5),data(i,6),[num2str(asin(1)*180*cvalues(i)/pi)]) % Assigns number to each ellipse
end

%%
%fill(A,B,ColorMap(1:200,3)','EdgeColor', 'None')
%%

% Adds colorbar to plot
colorbar('SouthOutside')
caxis([0 90])
axis equal;
%xlim([0 7649]);
%ylim([0 15927]);
grid on;
```

I get a picture that looks like this which I think works well:
[image]

Instead of adding numbers in the ellipses, I have added the angle I obtained (90 for circles, 0 for very long ellipse). Now is my real experiment i will have to plot several thousands ellipses, and we found out that it takes quite  alot of time to plot them, you'll see we tried another method to basically record the data and plot all in one go. But we haven't succeeded so far if you have any advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way using built-in colormaps in Matlab (look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html#inputarg_map) for a complete list).

The trick is to create a `n x 3` array where n is the number of colors you wish to represent. Here it's the number of ellipses.

You can create a colormap like so:

```
MyColorMap = jet(n)); %// jet or anything listed in the link above. You can also create your own colormap.
```

So that's what we're going to do in the following code. In order to get the order right, we need to sort the values of `asin(b/a)` and fetch each index for the right ellipse. The code is commented so it's quite easy to follow. I added 4 ellipses in the plot to see the difference in color better:

```
clear
clc
close all

%// Define dummy data
data = zeros(8,9);

data(:,5) = [3;5;12;8;2;7;4;6]; % Centre location X
data(:,6) = [1; -5 ;-2; 4;2;-3;9;5]; % Centre location Y
data(:,7) = [6 ;7;8;6;1;4;2;5]; % Major Axis a
data(:,8) = [2;5;4;2;2;5;3;7]; % Minor axis b

data(:,9) = [10;40;45;90;35;70;85;110]; % Angle of rotation phi

data(:,9)=data(:,9)*pi/180; % Converts phi in rads

theta = 0 : 0.01 : 2*pi;


%// Define colors here
cvalues = asin(data(:,8)./data(:,7));

%// Sort and get their index to access the color array
[~,idx] = sort(cvalues);

%// Create colormap with the "jet" colors
ColorMap = jet(numel(cvalues));
```

This is the array containing the "colors". It looks like this:

```
ColorMap =
                         0                         0                         1
                         0                       0.5                         1
                         0                         1                         1
                       0.5                         1                       0.5
                         1                         1                         0
                         1                       0.5                         0
                         1                         0                         0
                       0.5                         0                         0
```

So each row represents a combination of red, blue and green (RGB) and there are as many rows as there are ellipses to plot. Now filling the ellipses:

```
hold all
for i=1:numel(idx)

    k = idx(i);
    x = data(k,8)/2 * cos(theta) * cos(data(k,9)) - data(k,7)/2 * sin(theta) * sin(data(k,9)) + data(k,5);
    y = data(k,7)/2 * sin(theta) * cos(data(k,9)) + data(k,8)/2 * cos(theta) * sin(data(k,9)) + data(k,6);

    fill(x,y,ColorMap(i,:))

    plot(x, y, 'LineWidth', 1);

    % Label each ellipse with a number
    text(data(i,5),data(i,6),num2str(i),'Color','k','FontSize',12)


end
axis equal;
grid on;
```

Output with the `jet` colormap: blue is the first ellipse plotted and red is the last. You can add a colorbar if you want (add `colorbar`)

[image]

Using another colormap, the `bone` colormap, gives the following:

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Cool thanks very well. It works perfectly. I have 2 questions to make sure I understand I am quite in noob in matlab. I think I understand what [~,idx] = sort(cvalues); does. You are basically ranking the new variable from smallest to highest right? (although if you can explain what [~,idx] mean that would be great). Now I have added a colorbar, and as I expected it goes from 0 to 1. The variable arcsin gives me an angle in rad. I would like to have it in degree (which I guess I just change in the cvalues line). How do I get the colorbar to display 0° to 90° instead of 0 to 1. Thanks again

Comment: Actually it's not really working the way I want, I don't seem to get a good result. By calculating asin(b/a) i should get dark blue when I go towards circles and red for very long ellipses.

Comment: Oh then you can simply flip the output after performing the sort (`fliplr`) and that's gonna be fine. Or you can flip the `ColorMap` as well. For your other questions I'll get to them tomorrow since I don't have access to Matlab now sorry! I'll keep in touch as soon as I can.

Comment: No problem. I think I figured out something and it looks that it might be working, so maybe I can create a new post tomorrow to put the full code and the plot I get. However because I need to plot several thousands at the time we're trying to find a way to make it plot faster (we can wait up to 10 minutes right now)